# Pages migration from Lotus Notes 8.5 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am creating a tool for Lotus Notes(LN) to SharePoint migration using C#. 
The tool should have a capability of **migrating Pages** as well from LN to SP2013.

I am using **Interop.Domino.dll**, but didn't find any method to get pages from LN. Googled for it but did not find anything usefull.

Is there any other way to **migrate Pages** from **LN to SP2013**? Any **.dll**?
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to do is learn the structure of Domino databases. There are pages in Domino, but they play a very unimportant role mostly as static information. The thing you are looking for is documents: they contain the information that you want to migrate. If you want to migrate the design and functionality as well, then you have to read and understand Forms, Views, Subforms, XPages, Agents (Lotusscript, Javascript, Java, Formula), script libraries, Subforms, ...

There are big companies that tried to do what you try, and they have experienced Notes- Developers AND Sharepoint developers... And they mostly failed.

Migrating databases from Domino to sharepoint is a time consuming process that can be automated only in very small parts of the whole process:

1. analyze the business logic of the application (manual task)
2. analyze the different forms and their content (manual task)
3. develop sharepoint pages, backend code, frontend design to reproduce the look and feel (manual task)
4. read the documents from the domino database and migrate it to sharepoint. Convert Richtext into HTML, save attachments and embedded images, keep doclinks and other relationships between documents - this can be automated, if you have all the information of the previous steps...

Without learning domino, there will be no way for you to get the data...

Comment: Thank you Torsten :) It's really helpful. The migration tool that I have devloped is able to migrate 1. Data, 2.User groups, 3.Permissions etc. The only peoblem I am thinking of is to migrate pages, but I agree with you that pages are jsut the static contents and we can do it manually.